# Build a new matrix made of some source matrix rows given a row index vector

Tags: eigen3

I want to build a new matrix made of some source matrix rows given a vector of non consecutive indexes.

Namely, I'd like a row() function which take a list of indexes and returns the list of rows stored in a new matrix :

```
  VectorXi v = VectorXi::LinSpaced( 4, 10, 13);
  MatrixXi m = v.rowwise().replicate( 4 );
  VectorXi r1 ( ( VectorXi(3) <<  0,  3, 1 ).finished() );

  // Here is some pseudo code to create the desired matrix N :
  MatrixXi N = m.row(r1);

  cout << "m = " << m << endl;
  cout << "r1 = " << r1 << endl;
  cout << "N = " << N << endl;
```

Desired output :

```
m = 

10 10 10 10
11 11 11 11
12 12 12 12
13 13 13 13

r1 =
0
3
1

N =
10 10 10 10
13 13 13 13
11 11 11 11
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Sylvain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the development branch and (at least) C++11 enabled, you can write:

```
Eigen::MatrixXi N = m(r1,Eigen::all);
```

This is similar to the Matlab syntax:

```
N = m(r1, :);
```

You can also pass `{x,...}`-lists directly, or anything that behaves like an `std::vector<int>` (must provide a `size()` function and an `operator[]` and return an integral type), e.g.:

```
std::vector<int> c2{{3,0}};
std::cout << "m({2,1},c2) = \n" << m({2,1}, c2) << '\n';
```

These expressions are writable (assuming `m` itself is writable):

```
m({2,1}, c2) = Eigen::Matrix2i{{1,2},{3,4}};
std::cout << m << '\n';
```

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/cjacOY

Comment: Hi chtz, many thanks for this comprehensive and very pedagogical answer. I've seen indeed that v. 3.3.90 offered very nice facilities (
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html). Though, I've been developping a code which must be very reliable because it will be embedded into an important scientific system. Do you think it could be hazardous to base my software on the Eigen development branch ?.... Cheers. Sylvain

Comment: In general, the development branch should be save to use, but I would not dare to give any sort of promise or guarantee. Naturally, if your code is important you must make sure that **your code** is thoroughly and regularly unit-tested, especially every time you update your Eigen version (which you don't need to do that often). Even if Eigen was bug-free, there are plenty of ways it can be misused (and not everything is covered by assertions).

Comment: Hi chtz ! Do you know wether it exists some online Eigen dev versio documentation where what you described above is addressed ? Cheers !

Comment: Got it ! Sorry for the disturbance : https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html